# An topological basis for $X^*$ equipped with weak-star topology.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a real normed space. Let $B$ the closed unite ball in $X^*$, where the operator norm has been chosen for distance. Does the collection of all sets in the form  $\varepsilon B + L^{\perp} $, for all $\varepsilon > 0$ and $L$ being a finite dimension vector subspace of $L$, forms a (topological) local basis for $X^*$, when its topology is assumed weak-star ?

Note that  $$L^{\perp}:= \{x^*  \in X^* ~|~ \langle x^* , x \rangle =0,~ \forall x \in L  \}$$